# How to send multiple variables using birt report?

Tags: eclipse, db2, report, birt, maximo

Using the following query in db2:

```
select * from table where num in ('1a2334','1a43432','1a34243','1b34325','1b4545')
```

Now whenever I get data to report I get the rows like from the users:

```
1a23344
1a43432
1a34243
1b34325
1b45454
```

Then I use notepad++ to replace **rf** with **','** so it becomes

```
'1a2334','1a43432','1a34243','1b34325','1b4545'
```

What are my options for creating a report that accepts input easy enough for the average user?

This specific user has an excel sheet with multiple columns, I only use the first column (the mentioned examples above are rows from the first column).

A good solution provided by @Simulant, but I need this to get values from an excel file (preferably by copy paste). I noticed his/her solution uses static values, so I think I need dynamic values.
For the record I got the following error using the script:

> Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error:
>   TypeError: Cannot call method "replace" of null
>   (/report/data-sets/script-data-set[@id="12"]/method[@name="beforeOpen"]#3)
>   Script source:
>   /report/data-sets/script-data-set[@id="12"]/method[@name="beforeOpen"],
>   line: 0, text:
>   __bm_beforeOpen(). (Element ID:1)  Error.ScriptEvaluationError ( 1 time(s) ) detail : org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException:
>   There are errors evaluating script "var parameters =
>   params["multiSelectParameter"].value; var replacesPart = "'" +
>   parameters.join("', '") + "'"; this.queryText =
>   this.queryText.replace("replaceMe", replacesPart);":

Answer (score 3):

Create a Report with a Multi-Select Parameter. Create a List Box Parameter and allow multiple values. You can add static values or select `dynamic` and display the result of another query.

[image]

Write your query as following SQL-Statement:

```
select * from table where num in (replaceMe);
```

Select your Data-Set and select the `script` Tab. Enter for the `beforeOpen` the following script. This replaces the placeholder `replaceMe` in your SQL-Statement with the concatinated values of your Multi-Select Parameter enclosed with single quotes `'` and separated with commas `,` as you need it:

```
var parameters = params["multiSelectParameter"].value;
var replacesPart = "'" + parameters.join("', '") + "'";
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("replaceMe", replacesPart);
```

Comment: this looked to be a good solution, but it doesn't work as I expected, the user will has a list with values (I don't previously have and shouldn't be updated everything). I need something so the user can select one excel row and copy-paste it in this report, without my help.